# Check remote directory size before file transfer in SFTP

Tags: linux, sftp

I have to check remote directory size before transferring file using SFTP. Please help how this can be achieved? I will transfer file only if remote directory size is less than defined threshold.

Comment: Linux shell scripting? Perl? What have you tried so far? Please write a question according to [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: I have tried shell script for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the following command

```
ssh USER@SERVER du -bs "/path/to/remote/directory"
```

and capture its output.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Is there any way I can use -h option with du command?

Comment: @karan Yes you can replace `-b` with `-h` (or `-k` or `-m`) if you want.